# MongoDB find query with date comparison

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

In mongodb collection I saved date as a string.

I want to fetch documents which were inserted in last 24 hours. Below is my code-

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date yest = new Date();
    Date now = new Date();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(now);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1440);
    yest = cal.getTime();

    String dToN = sdf.format(now);
    String dToY = sdf.format(yest);
    System.out.println("Yest:"+dToY);
    System.out.println("Now:"+dToN)

  BasicDBObject find = new BasicDBObject("retryCount", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 0));
    find.append("status",1);
    find.append("deliveryTime",new BasicDBObject("$gte", dToY));
    find.append("deliveryTime",new BasicDBObject("$lte", dToN));
    cursor = coll.find(find);
    int misCount = cursor.count();
```

But my date comparison code is not working. I am getting count 0 everytime. 
What's wrong in this code ?

Comment: The answer given should fix your issue. I added an explanation to why this is so in the comments to it.

Answer (score 0):

Update date comparison code as follows :

```
DBObject dateQuery = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", yest).add("$lte", now).get();
find.put("deliveryTime", dateQuery);
```

Comment: To explain this response. You actually want to pass in the Date object  (modified as shown) and not the strings. In the mongo shell, dates may look like strings but they are actually numbers from *epoch* time internally. The driver is handling the conversions for you properly.

Comment: @Sidd while I open an IDE. can you test your query in the mongo shell with values you expect to see if it returns anything. And also check that your System.out debugging was giving you the dates you expected.

Comment: @NeilLunn I am firing this query from umongo- {"deliveryTime":{"$gte":"2014-02-05 14:58:36","$lte":"2014-02-06 14:58:36"}, "retryCount":{"$gt":0}, "status":1}  and getting count 97

Comment: Ouch. Those are strings. That's your problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn Any alternate ?

Comment: @Sidd. Yep new answer. It's not pretty, but best get it over with. Lexical comparison shouldn't be relied on.

Answer (score 0):

So from the conversation chain the problem is that documents in the collection actually have strings in the `deliveryTime` field. You may have this in a number of places if your code on inserts and updates has been doing similar conversions. Also the internal format is UTC which is probably not what your strings are. The driver is meant to handle this for you.

It is advised that you get your dates converted in your collections and look at all the areas writing or reading as strings.

The following will show how to use date objects and how they will serialize:

```
    Date now = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(now);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    Date yest = cal.getTime();

    BasicDBObject timeNow  = new BasicDBObject("now", now );
    BasicDBObject timeThen = new BasicDBObject("then" yest)
    System.out.println( timeNow );
    System.out.println( timeThen );
```

**Note:** Though the output displays as below. It's still not passing in a string, but an epoch timstamp on a BSON timestamp type.

```
{ "this" : { "$date" : "2014-02-06T10:50:05.873Z"}}
```

Comment: You mean I have to change the format when I insert documents in a collection and according to you there is no way to compare date If it was inserted as a string. right ?

Comment: It would be advised. In essence you are doing all the heavy lifting, converting and parsing strings in your in-line code. That includes doing timezone conversions etc etc. You're also shooting yourself in the foot for any date math that could be done server side in the future. The alternative is getting your string formats and timezone things in sync with the results and chancing on everything will be in lexical order **always**, and that no-one does something differently. Some pain now for resolving future pains.